# Exiting insert mode: end of line behaviour with jj

Tags: vim

In `.vimrc`:

```
inoremap jj <Esc>
```

Given a file containing:

```
foo
bar
```

With the cursor at `f` in normal mode, hit <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>. Cursor is now at `o`.

With the cursor at `f` in normal mode, hit <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>. Cursor is now down a line at `b`.

1. Why?
2. How can I prevent this behaviour (ie make <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> work identically to <kbd>Esc</kbd>)?

Comment: I can't reproduce this; there might be something else in your `.vimrc` file

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was odd. I'll try paring down and see.

Comment: Well, it took me another hour, but I tracked it down and feel kinda stupid now. Trailing whitespace! I'll post an answer on the off-chance anyone else commits the same blunder.

Comment: `:%s/\s\+$//`.  Also `highlight Badspace ctermfg=red ctermbg=red
<newline-here> match Badspace /\s\+$/`

Comment: Noted, thanks! Once bitten twice shy...

Comment: Or use [my ShowTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3966).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though I've been using Vim for several years, this one caught me off-guard. After paring down the entire .vimrc to the single line containing the remap, I was still seeing the behaviour described in the question. Creating a brand new .vimrc and typing that binding anew removed the problem.

In the end I realised I'd bound <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> by leaving trailing whitespace behind. It must have crept in during a recent revamping of my rc files. <kbd>Space</kbd> pressed at the end of line progresses to the next line.

Leaving evidence of my boneheadedness in case it saves someone a few hours someday.

Comment: That’s a reason for `:set list` with proper `set listchars=…` (see doc). @ExplosionPills’ variant needs autocmd to work with multiple windows setup.